# What dialogue tag can be used to describe being confused?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, phrases, dialogue

For example; My brother was standing in front of my room. “Are you ok with this?” He huffs.
“What do you mean?” [A term that would describe that she is confused]

Comment: Puzzled. But I would put simply [Stares]. It's clear from the context that she is confused. [Stares] would just enhance it in a slightly humorous way. I don't know if my intuition is right that you intend this to be funny.

Comment: I think what you're wanting is something which is more succinct than "he responded, confused". Unfortunately, your question isn't very clear. Including this comment, there are three replies to your question, all different.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Dialogue can add flavour to your writing or stories. Dialogue is that
> through which you can communicate with the others clearly and
> smoothly. So,no need to get confused ,dialogue tag can be used in the
> beginning, middle or end of the sentences. for example: My brother was
> standing in front of my room. “Are you ok with this?” He huffs. “What
> do you mean?” This simply tells that she couldn't believe that her
> brother was there standing infront of her room and seeing his brother
> her expression was difficult to predict,she seems bit bemuse.

Comment: Is the quoted passage something you've written? If not, what's the source?

Comment: It's something I've written.